# Setup git repository on network folder & NAS

Tags: git

I'm new to git and I'm trying to set up my own repository.

I have a mapped network folder of my NAS where I want to store the working files and edit them. Then I would like to Push the changes to another network drive (raspberry pi with openhab running).

After reading a lot of tutorials I am able to create a repository on the pi network folder and clone it to my NAS network folder.

But when I push changes to the Pi, the files there do not change. I need a solution where I just push and the files changes without further actions.

How do I set this up?

Comment: Pushing will not change the content of the working tree of the remote repo. In order for that to happen, you need to merge/checkout/something *on the pi*.

Comment: Git does not push *files*. Git pushes *commits*. That's the root of your issue here. Having pushed some commits, you probably want to *deploy* one of them. It's possible to use Git as a deployment tool, the same way it's possible to use a wrench as a hammer. Don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments, you have to differentiate `working tree` and `repository` and when|how which entities are used.

In addition, I'll note some more things (partially related):

- **NEVER** work with *non-local* repos directly, even NAS-mounted tree has a significant chance to be corrupted sooner or later (sad, but true - it can happen with working tree and repo)
- You have grok git-hooks, understand which and when are started and add needed hooks in both repos ("push after commit" to local and "update working tree after incoming push" to remote)

HTH

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast responses.

Ok i understood the difference of pushing only commits not files. So i will start a local repo and learn about git-hooks.